# Seeking insights on the origin of the term "Peripatetic Axiom"

Tags: aristotle, aquinas, history

I have been researching the origins of the "Peripatetic Axiom," which states that nothing is in the mind that was not first in the senses. While I understand that this principle was first formulated by Aristotle and later expounded upon by Aquinas, I am curious about the term "Peripatetic" that is associated with it.

I understand that the Peripatetic School was founded by Aristotle, and it seems likely that this axiom was closely associated with his teachings. However, I am curious about how central this view was to ancient Aristotelians compared to medieval schoolmen. Were there any differences in attitudes or interpretations of this axiom between these two groups?

I would also like to know if the term "Peripatetic Axiom" was coined by Aquinas or if it existed prior to his work. If anyone has any information on who first called it the "Peripatetic Axiom" or when and where it began to be referred to by this name, I would be grateful for any insights

Comment: Aristotle never wrote anything like that, but some scholars (Wee, Aquinas and Locke) point to *De Anima* III.7, 431b2:"*Intellect thinks the forms in images... so, apart from sense-perception, when it is concerned with images, it is moved*". Not exactly it. In Aquinas, the phrase is buried in a commentary to question 2 of *De Veritate*. It seems to have been plucked from obscurity by Locke and Leibniz. The latter added "*except for intellect itself*" to it and distinguished it as "axiom" in *Nouveaux Essais*. The nickname "peripatetic" seems to be late addition for convenience of reference.

Comment: IMO it is a recent name, applied to Aquinas' dictum ["*Nihil est in intellectu quod non sit prius in sensu*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peripatetic_axiom)

Comment: @Conifold 1) this is the best answer I have found thus far. Thankyou very much.

2) so do you think my vague sense that it is something well known and commonly accepted by many Thomist scholastics is a mere fantasy?

Comment: I wouldn't call it a fantasy. Aristotle's theory of cognition can be fairly surmised as supporting Aquinas's nutshell interpretation, albeit not exactly in the spirit of modern empiricism. Modern non-religious scholars also say that "Aristotle can be classed as a *tabula rasa* empiricist", see [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/empiricism-ancient-medieval/#ArisEmpi), but he would probably accept Leibniz's stipulation (as, I suspect, would Aquinas):"Aristotle is not a cognitive empiricist, since at a key point he relies on a rationalist, indeed “super-rationalist” view of cognition."